# Bootstrap Dropdown Menu - Multiple Columns Side-by-Side

Tags: drop-down-menu, bootstrap-5, grid-layout

Trying to create a filter on a web page that utilizes Bootstrap's drop-down menu and places the columns side-by-side, but instead it stacks them right now. The filter menu is created dynamically by looping through an array of items I want to create and. each item is a new column I want to place on my menu. I was trying to utilize the grid layout (`container > row > column`) with the class `row-cols-#` on my row element but that does not work as I thought it would.

I can force my menu to be a certain width and make the columns position correctly, but then my menu is hardcoded to a certain width on all filter menu regardless of the number of columns. Here is sample of my HTML code that is creating a rather big menu.

Wondering if my `d-flex` at the very end is what causes problems for my grid layout

```
<div
  class="ms-auto py-4"
  id="PageFilter"
>
  <div class="dropdown filter">
    <button
      class="btn btn-outline-secondary d-flex align-items-center dropdown-toggle"
      type="button"
      data-bs-toggle="dropdown"
    >
      <img
        src="/static/icons/bootstrap/sliders2.svg"
        class="me-2"
        height="25"
      />
      Filter
      <span class="badge bg-danger ms-4">0</span>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end shadow" style="">
      <form action="/ajax/page_filter/" method="GET" class="filter">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">Region</h6>
              <hr class="mt-0" />
              <div
                class="overflow-y-auto filter-list"
                style="max-height: 400px"
              >
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-0-0">
                      ITEM 1
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-0-1">
                      ITEM 2
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">State</h6>
              <hr class="mt-0" />
              <div
                class="overflow-y-auto filter-list"
                style="max-height: 400px"
              >
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-1-0">
                      ITEM 1
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-1-1">
                      ITEM 2
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-1-2">
                      ITEM 3
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-1-3">
                      ITEM 4
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-1-4">
                      ITEM 5
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-1-5">
                      ITEM 6
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-1-6">
                      ITEM 7
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-1-7">
                      ITEM 8
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-auto">
              <h6 class="dropdown-header">TSC</h6>
              <hr class="mt-0" />
              <div
                class="overflow-y-auto filter-list"
                style="max-height: 400px"
              >
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-2-0">
                      ITEM 1
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row align-items-center mx-2">
                  <div class="form-check">
                    <input/>
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="filter-2-1">
                      ITEM 2
                    </label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-4">
              <button type="reset" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning clear-filter">
                Clear Filter
              </button>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger ms-2">
                Submit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I've included my current example here [Filter Menu Help](https://codeply.com/v/957ai6U6Fu)

Comment: I don't see/understand the issue: https://codeply.com/p/DPEYEKR9l8

Comment: @Zim - interesting. That must mean I need to look further how I am structuring the web page. I've included an update with the example I am seeing. Maybe that might help troubleshoot more.

Comment: Hey @Zim - where you able to view my updated code-by snippet?